# How to detect if an application is running under KVM?

Tags: c++, c, virtualization, virtual-machine

I already know how to detect VMWare and VirtualPC, but I want to know how to do this in [Kernel Virtual Machine](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page). I would like the code to be in C or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.dmo.ca/blog/detecting-virtualization-on-linux/) implies that it's enough to check the kernel's boot messages, if Linux is your hosted OS:

```
 # dmesg | grep -i virtual
 CPU: AMD QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.9.1 stepping 03
```

That should be easy enough to implement in C.

Comment: if you run a wmi query on win32_computersystem you will see that the manufacturer and model store vm vendor. but i dont know how to run a wmi query in c

Comment: To use WMI in C, you have to go through COM.