Detect if running inside QEMU
I'm working on some bare metal Cortex-M4 code. It usually runs on a dev board, but to run unit tests I emulate it under QEMU. However, some hardware configurations are done differently depending on whether it's running on the board or QEMU -- for instance, stdout is redirected to SWO if running on the board, and to USART if running under QEMU.
Currently I have a build-time flag that determines whether to run it under QEMU or not. However to make the user experience a little better I would like to avoid that. As such I'm wondering whether there's a way to check, at runtime, if the code is running on the board or under QEMU. Say, reading a memory address which will give different outputs for QEMU and the board. I know if emulation is bug-free it should behave exactly like the board, but maybe the QEMU developers hid something somewhere that I could check.

So you want to have one binary that you can run on both? You say Currently I have a build-time flag why not change that to a runtime flag? I don’t know how the setup is but might a shared library that contains the different implementation details be an option?

Would this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109283/how-to-detect-if-an-application-is-running-under-kvm

@t.niese my goal is to change to a runtime flag. The whole issue is detecting whether I'm running in the board or under emulation, so I can make the proper configurations in each case.

@Renat I'm afraid not as this is a bare-metal board, it doesn't (and I believe can't) run Linux.

I found a possible solution. An information that was missing from my question is that I'm running on an STM32F4DISCOVERY board, with the STM32F407VG MCU, whereas in QEMU I'm emulating it with the olimex-stm32-h405 target (which is similar enough for my purposes).
According to the reference manual for the STM32F405/F407 (and other models), in Section 38.6.1, the MCU ID code (DBGMCU_IDCODE) at address 0xE0042000 should return 0x413 for the last 12 bits if running on a 405 or 407 MCU. Running on a real board this is indeed what is read from that address. However, apparently this isn't implemented by QEMU, so a read from that address returns 0.
I know this is relying on an unimplemented feature of QEMU and may break in the future if they do decide to implement it. But lacking a better suggestion, I will probably go with this now, and if it breaks later I'll reassess.
